# operator overloading for primitive types

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, primitive

I am using a class as a wrapper to hold a group of several unsigned shorts that represent different options or characteristics. Each short is initialized to be a power of two so I can easily add or or them together.

```
public static class Options
{
    public static readonly ushort OPTN0 = 1 << 0; // 0001
    public static readonly ushort OPTN1 = 1 << 1; // 0010
    public static readonly ushort OPTN2 = 1 << 2; // 0100
    ...
}


public static void main(string[] args)
{
    funcThatUsesOptns(Option.OPTN0); // works fine
    funcThatUsesOptns(Option.OPTN1 | Option.OPTN2); // fails because '|' returns int
    funcThatUsesOptns((ushort)(Option.OPTN0 | Option.OPTN2)); // works fine
    ...
}
```

However, since "+" and "|" both return ints in this situation, I have to cast them every time I do. For example, both a and b are initialized as ints:

```
var a = Option.OPTN0 + Option.OPTN1;
var b = Option.OPTN0 | Option.OPTN1;
```

So I was wondering if operator overloading was possible for primitive types. If not, are there any better ways of achieving this? Of course it isn't going to kill me to just cast it every time, but I was hoping for a cleaner way.

Edit:
I am actually using this to render a lot of simple geometric objects (cubes, pyramids,...). I would like to be able to quickly tell the renderer which faces to draw. If a face on one object is touching another or is facing away from the camera, I can set the corresponding bit to tell the renderer not to draw that face.

Comment: Why not define your "options" as `int` and change `funcThatUsesOptns` to take `int`?

Comment: Any reason you aren't using Enums with the `Flags` attribute?

Comment: I tried using flags, but unless I was doing it wrong (very likely) I still needed to cast

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe you can overload operators between 2 primitives, you can overload between a custom class or struct and a primitive, but not between 2 primitives

Comment: What is the problem with casting?

Comment: Like I said, it isn't a huge problem. Just a little annoying and a bit ugly to look at. I generally try to find other cleaner (in my opinion) ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like what you really want here are enum values based on ushort, like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum Options : ushort
{
     OPTN0 = 1 << 0, // 0001
     OPTN1 = 1 << 1, // 0010
     OPTN2 = 1 << 2, // 0100    
}
```

Then you can make use of the built-in `|` operator for enums. You would, however, have to change the signature of your methods to access the `Options` enum type instead of a ushort.

```
funcThatUsesOptns(Option.OPTN0 | Option.OPTN1);
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I will probably do. one more question though, what would be the best way of checking for individual bits on the other side?

Comment: Ahh. Nevermind, the HasFlag function looks like it will work nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

```
[Flags]
public enum MyOptions : ushort {
    OPTN0 = 1 << 0,
    OPTN1 = 1 << 1,
    OPTN2 = 1 << 2,
    OPTN3 = 1 << 3,
}
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately its still making me cast when I do this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the closest you'll get to operator overloading on 2 primitives would be making an extension method.  Unfortunately you wouldn't be able to do a true operator overload that way, but it might be an acceptable solution:

```
public static ushort LogicalOr(this ushort s1, ushort s2)
{
    return (ushort)(s1 | s2);
}
```

---

```
funcThatUsesOptns(Option.OPTN1.LogicalOr(Option.OPTN2));
```

Changing to enum like the other answers is also a good solution if you are OK with changing your function signatures.